# Copy to USB flash drive is very slow

Tags: usb

Copying 258Mb to a Corsair formatted NTFS starts fast then slows dramatically to 339kB/sec at the end, 20 minutes later. These are USB3 sticks on USB3 ports on my W530 Thinkpad.
After reading the posts I formatted the 35Gb Corsair with ext4 and now it isn't seen at all on neither of my Ubuntu 16.4 Ubuntu machines.
The only way I can copy seems to be using Deja'dup to external HDDs or by burning DVDs. I say "seems" as I have not tried a restore yet.
Anyone have any ideas? Are there any drivers that I can download. I'm trying to hang in there until a new machine hopefully arrives in a month or so
- Thanks - 
Garoolgan

Comment: Try according to the following link (and links from it), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035 Maybe the USB 3 pendrives are not working well with your computer's USB system. You can check that by trying in some other computer(s) and with some other USB pendrive(s).

Comment: Can you check the last few lines of the output of `dmesg` (type this command into a terminal) a few seconds after plugging in your USB sticks? If any errors occurred, they should be visible there. Anyway, a slowdown in USB write speed is generally a normal thing, as the real maximum write speed is the one you experience in the end, whereas the quick start is due to caching the data to write in RAM. I do agree that USB 3 should support faster speed than 400kB/s though, at least several MB/s (compare e.g. http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3.0-thumb-drive-review,3477-2.html)

Comment: The results are very long but here are the last few lines starting with a mention of Corsair>>>>

Comment: 16640.887109] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Corsair  Voyager 3.0      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[16640.887827] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[16640.889323] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 62685184 512-byte logical blocks: (32.1 GB/29.9 GiB)
[16640.889455] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[16640.889461] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[16640.889596] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[16640.891632]  sdb: sdb1
[16640.897990] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
admin10561@admin10561-ThinkPad-W530:~$ ^C

Comment: When I did a new clean install on a new 240Gb SSD disk the speed of USB transfers came back to near the manufactuer's speeds.